# Dogecoin qt build compiling error libdb_cxx headers missing

Tags: dogecoin, compiling

When I run

MSYS shell:

> ./autogen.sh
>   BOOST_ROOT=../boost_1_55_0 ./configure --disable-tests

I got the error:

> error libdb_cxx headers missing

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you installed berkleydb?

Comment: yes I have, but when I was compiling sources an error appeared                                                                                                                                                                                                           but fixed with this way: [link](https://bitcointa.lk/threads/how-do-you-build-berkeley-db-4-8-30-in-mingw.34771/)

Comment: All of this is in MinGW